# Trim to remove white space

Tags: jquery, trim

`jQuery` `trim` not working. I wrote the following command to remove white space. Whats wrong in it?

```
var str = $('input').val();

str = jquery.trim(str);
console.log(str);
```

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/dMr2C/) example.

Comment: `.trim()` only removes white spaces at the start and end of the string. Could you put up a sample page on jsbin.com if you're not seeing this?

Comment: post your string which you are trying to trim

Comment: thanks to all..... very much... i was stuck by using small Q

Comment: whic is beter solution 
str.trim(); or  $.trim(str)  what is def bw these two

Answer (score 120, accepted):

`jQuery.trim()` capital Q?

or `$.trim()`

**Edit (2021): This answer is 11 years old (2010). There are better solutions posted below.**

Comment: JavaScript *does* have a native `.trim()` method - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4040259/trim-to-remove-white-space/28017159#28017159

Comment: Thank you for this tip, sir :)

Comment: **2020 Update**: as of [jQuery v3.5.0](https://blog.jquery.com/2020/04/10/jquery-3-5-0-released/) , `$.trim(mystr)` is deprecated. Use JS native `mystr.trim()`.

Answer (score 76):

### No need for jQuery

JavaScript *does* have a native [`.trim()` method](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/Trim).

```
var name = "    John Smith  ";
name = name.trim();

console.log(name); // "John Smith"
```

[**Example Here**](http://jsfiddle.net/km6ho2mo/)

> [String.prototype.trim()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/Trim)
>
> The trim() method removes whitespace from both ends of a string. Whitespace in this context is all the whitespace characters (space, tab, no-break space, etc.) and all the line terminator characters (LF, CR, etc.).

Comment: Nice. Thanks Josh

Comment: Keep in mind that these methods don't work exactly the same with different types of values, e.g. calling `$.trim(undefinedVariable)` will result in empty string, but calling `undefinedVariable.trim()` will cause TypeError

Answer (score 11):

or just use `$.trim(str)`

Answer (score 9):

Why not try this?

**html:**

```
<p>
  a b c
</p>
```

**js:**

```
$("p").text().trim();
```

Answer (score 2):

Try this

```
  $('input').val($('input').val().trim());
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved by adding more information on what the code does and how it helps the OP.