# $.trim spaces at beginning and end of text input value

Tags: jquery

So I'm trying to trim any spaces BEFORE and AFTER the text input value...

Any ideas? Driving me nuts. I tried reading up on `$.trim()`. But can't get it to work properly.

Code:

```
var campaign_values = {
        name : $.trim($('.nameField').val().toLowerCase().replace(/\s/g, "_")),
        // other variables...
};
```

Comment: How do you use the `$.trim` function?

Comment: Are you having whitespace issues. `.trim()` removes whitespace at the beginning and end of an input, I have never had this issue with a text field. Can you show us how you implemented the code?

Comment: Wrapped it around the entire $().val() variable...

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4040259/jquery-trim-to-remove-white-space

Comment: Your inner .replace() is removing all spaces (and replacing them with _, this is preventing $.trim() from having anything to remove

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Not sure what problem you were having with trim, but you should be able to use it like this:

```
var campaign_values = {
        name : $.trim($('.nameField').val()).toLowerCase().replace(/\s/g, "_"),
        // other variables...
};
```

Though in this case, I think it is clearer to use javascript `trim()`

```
var campaign_values = {
        name : $('.nameField').val().trim().toLowerCase().replace(/\s/g, "_"),
        // other variables...
};
```

Comment: First one is not working for some reason, but I got the second one to work! Thanks!! Swear I tried this... Option #2 is much cleaner! Cheers!

Comment: The first one doesn't do anything because you are first replacing all spaces(including leading and ending) with `"_"`. It should be `$.trim($('.nameField').val()).toLowerCase().replace(/\s/g, "_")` Is the native .trim() method supported in IE 6/7/8? according to MDN support started in IE9 https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/Trim

Comment: @KevinB Kevin, you are correct.  I didn't really look at the replace call there closely when writing up my answer. I have edited to reflect this.

Answer (score 4):

Try using `$.trim` before calling `replace` function:

```
name : $.trim($('.nameField').val()).toLowerCase().replace(/\s/g, "_"),
```

Comment: I like this option too...but went for the `.val().trim()...` option. A little cleaner and easier to read! Thanks!

Comment: @MikeBarwick You are welcome, note that `trim` doesn't work in older browsers.

Answer (score 0):

The standard JavaScript String.trim() will remove the beginning and end whitespace from a string.

```
"   string  ".trim() ==  "string"
```

Comment: .trim() is not implemented in all browsers, so be careful (this one got me recently)