# How to use trim function on an object to remove whitespaces jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have an object 'data' and it has some elements, some of them have null value. When i am printing them instead of whitespace null is printed.

Example:

```
console.log(data.value1);
console.log(data.value2);
console.log(data.value3);
```

Output is :

```
null
null
null
```

But when using

```
$.trim(data.value1);
$.trim(data.value2);
$.trim(data.value3);
```

Problem is solved.

Now how can i use trim on object so i dont have to write same code for all the elements.

Comment: Why do you need to do this? The reason you see `null` in the console is because that's the value of the property. You see `''` when using `$.trim()` as the property is coerced to a string. There is absolutely no point looping through to make all `null` values in to `''` as the coercion will happen automatically when you use the property.

Comment: Iterate properties and update them with trimmed content;

Comment: No need for jQuery.  Just add a default value like so: console.log( data.value1 || "");

Comment: jQuery.trim() or $.trim() http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4040259/trim-to-remove-white-space

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try:

```
Object.keys(data).forEach(function(key) {
   data[key] = $.trim(data[key]);
});
```